# use variable's name JavaScript (literally)

Tags: javascript, variables

How can I refer to the variable's name (literally the name of the variable)?

I have the following code:

```
var thisVariableName = 'path/filename.js';

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.id = **I WANT THE TEXT "thisVariableName" to be added HERE**
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = thisVariableName;
```

So that if output script.id, I would get thisVariableName as such, not the value of the variable

AFTER SOME OF THE RESPONSES:

I want to systematize the addition of many script files. 
In the example below I add four files, but imagine I had to add 30+ files (please reserve yourself from asking why would I need to add 30+ files; after all this is the promise of computing)

As of now, the only way I know how to get this done is to create two separate arrays; array 1 for the files' name string, and array 2 for the files' paths, or ALTERNATIVELLY, as Felix Kling SUGGESTS create an object per each variable:

```
var jQueryPath = 'js/jquery-1.5.1.js';
var jQueryUICore = 'js/jquery.ui.core.js';
var jQueryUIWidget = 'js/jquery.ui.widget.js';
var jQueryUITabs = 'js/jquery.ui.tabs.js';

var fileNames = new Array ('jQueryPath','jQueryUICore','jQueryUIWidget','jQueryUITabs');

var filePaths = new Array (jQueryPath,jQueryUICore,jQueryUIWidget,jQueryUITabs);

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 

for (var i=0;i<4;i++){

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('id',fileNames[i]);
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', filePaths[i]);
    head.appendChild(script);

    }
```

So whether I create arrays to hold the names and the values of the variables, or create an object, it requires individual creation of both attributes per file.

I was hoping I could reference the literal variables' names of an array composed of the variables; i.e:

```
var onlyOneArray = new Array (jQueryPath,jQueryUICore,jQueryUIWidget,jQueryUITabs);

for (var i=0;i<4;i++){

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('id',**onlyOneArra[i] the NAME**);
        script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        script.setAttribute('src', onlyOneArray[i]);
        head.appendChild(script);

        }
```

Comment: confused me. Why don't you just typein the name ? You would need to access the variable anyhow regardless if this is possible or not.

Comment: add quotes around the name to make it a literal string

Comment: Bad idea: but you could use eval() to save the var name in a string then initialise it.

Comment: Variables are names that you (the programmer) know that hold unknown/variable content. If you don't know the variable name, then you have nothing to work with. You'd need at least a variable to hold the variable name then.

Comment: Why exactly do you want this? Perhaps telling what you want to achieve may get you a proper answer.

Comment: You should not create an object for **each** variable. You should set all script names / paths as property of **one** object (that's why I named it script**s** ;)) and then loop over it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot get the name of a variable at run time.

I suggest to follow a more organized approach, e.g. by storing the variable as property of an object. You can then iterate over this object:

```
var scripts = {
    thisVariableName: 'path/filename.js'
};

for(var name in scripts) {
    if(scripts.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.id = name;
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = scripts[name];
        //....
    }
}
```

**Update:** Regarding your changes, what you should end up doing, is :

```
var scripts = {
    jQueryPath: 'js/jquery-1.5.1.js',
    jQueryUICore: 'js/jquery.ui.core.js',
    jQueryUIWidget: 'js/jquery.ui.widget.js',
    jQueryUITabs: 'js/jquery.ui.tabs.js'
};

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

for(var name in scripts) {
    if(scripts.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('id', name);
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.setAttribute('src', scripts[name]);
        head.appendChild(script);
   }
}
```

Comment: @elusive: Yeah, never forget this **ever** if you post code here on SO. Otherwise you get punished so badly for it ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: Exactly. Most of the people i talked to had no idea what this is good for. I am always happy to see that somebody knows it ;)

Comment: For people that are wondering what is `hasOwnProperty`: It tells if the object has the property and it is not inherited (like `toString`). More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Thanks you Felix Kling. I am wondering how is it that the variable has the property name when it has not been explicitly attributed? Where can I find more info on this?

Comment: @Ibero: I'm not really sure what you mean, but you can have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 3):

```
script.id = "thisVariableName";
```

? There's no way you would create variables like that at runtime (and it's somewhat impossible), therefore you have to already know the name of the variable... just put it in a string. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding? Is this in another script? Are you referring to it with a different variable? Do you want it to be passed, then read the name afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the name of the variable, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings as property names of Object objects, or you can use them for variable names (i.e. properties of the variable/activation object) with `eval`. Whatever you do, you must associate the variable name with a value at some point, so why not just craete an object:

```
var scripts = {
  jQueryPath: 'js/jquery-1.5.1.js',
  jQueryUICore: 'js/jquery.ui.core.js',
  jQueryUIWidget: 'js/jquery.ui.widget.js',
  jQueryUITabs: 'js/jquery.ui.tabs.js'
};
```

The *eval* equivalent is very similar except you'd provide an array of just the variable names and use `eval()` to get the values. But that assumes that the variables have already been created and assigned values via some mechanism that would probably look very much like the above anyway. Also, *eval* is very inefficient and not recommended when a plain object will do the job far more efficiently.